# Como pegar apenas o dia/mês/ano separadamente de um Input Date

Tags: javascript, data

Estou aprendendo [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) e tentando fazer um programa que calcular o dia exato que uma pessoa nasceu.
Pra isso eu criei um formulário de data no [html](/questions/tagged/html) e ele me retorna por exemplo: **2010-06-21...** Para que eu consiga calcular o dia exato do nascimento da pessoa, preciso pegar separadamente `input:date` o dia/mês/ano e colocar eles em uma **variável**. Já tentei de várias formas e não consegui, alguém pode me ajudar? O meu código está assim:

```js
function calcular (){
    var d = document.querySelector('input#data').value
    alert(d)
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Modelo de exercicio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h4>Descubra o dia da semana que você nasceu</h4>
        </header>
        <section>
            <div id = 'primeiro'>
               Coloque sua data de nascimento
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="date" name="data" id="data">
            <input type="button" name = 'botao' id='botao' value="Calcular" onclick="calcular()">
            <div>
                .
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; CursoemVideo</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [edit] e **coloque o código/erro como texto**. Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774)

Comment: Não use cumprimentos ou saudações, veja [que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

O `value` de um elemento `<input>` é sempre uma *string*, no caso de uma data, ela vem no formato *YYYY-MM-DD* (ano-mês-dia).

Você pode separar a string utilizando o caractere `-` como separador, ou então utilizar os métodos de um objeto do tipo *Date* para recuperar o dia/mês/ano.

**Exemplos**

Utilizando split:

```
var d = document.querySelector('input#data').value;
var [ano, mes, dia] = d.split('-');
```

Utilizando split novamente, mas dessa vês convertendo a *string* para *number*:

```
var d = document.querySelector('input#data').value;
var [ano, mes, dia] = d.split('-').map(Number);
```

Utilizando *Date*:

```
var d = document.querySelector('input#data').valueAsDate;
var dia = d.getUTCDate();
var mes = d.getUTCMonth() + 1; // meses iniciam com o valor 0 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
var ano = d.getUTCFullYear();
```